# How to check a sub-stack of a stack?

Tags: java, stack

By asking that question I mean for example:

```
subStack:[7,15,9]
```

And the main stack:

```
mainStack:[45,24,18,7,8,233,91,531,7,15,9,45,32,1]
```

What I'm asked for is - if `subStack` is somewhere in `mainStack`.

I am struggling with it all over my papers I would be happy to get some help. Thanks!

Comment: You could pop all the elements of the mainStack in a loop and check if they are in the subStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s1- main stack, s2 - sub stack?? and s3 - temp stack

You can peek and compare on both the stacks s1 and s2, if they are matching you can pop from s1 and s2, store pop of s2 in s3. if s2 becomes empty s2 is substack of s1 else restore s2 from s3, repeat the steps until either s1 or s2 becomes empty

```
private boolean isSubStack(java.util.Stack<Integer> s1, java.util.Stack<Integer> s2) {
    while (!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty()) {
        while (!s1.isEmpty() && s1.peek() != s2.peek()) {
            s1.pop();
        }
        java.util.Stack<Integer> s3 = new java.util.Stack<Integer>();
        while (!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty() && s2.peek().equals(s1.peek())) {
            s1.pop();
            s3.push(s2.pop());
        }
        if (!s2.isEmpty()) {
            while (!s3.isEmpty()) {
                s2.push(s3.pop());
            }
        }
    }
    return s2.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: There is a problem: 

If you will have in [s1] 1 or more of the numbers that [s2] contain, it will end returning false every time, even if you have a row of numbers like in [s1] at the end of [s2] (if you won't have the peek of s2 anytime, only in case [s1] is actually the subStack of [s2]

Comment: can you please update the question with the inputs, will check

Comment: At the beginning of the mainStack, with the input example, I mentioned in the post - there is a 7 in the beginning of the stack, what I meant is when the head of the mainStack will be 7 and the rest won't be 15 for ex: 3, it will stop there and return false.